# Can any Delone set be approximated by a model set?

Tags: discrete-geometry

Let $\Lambda \subset \mathbb{R}^d$ be a Delone set (uniformly discrete and relatively dense). I would like to know whether $\Lambda$ can be approximated by a model set in the Hausdorff distance.

Here is part of an attempted proof. Let $L = \mathbb{Z}^n \subset \mathbb{R}^n, n>d.$ Choose any subspace $H \subset \mathbb{R}^n$ which is in irrational position with respect to $L$ and consider the cut and project set 
$$\Lambda_W := \{ \pi_1(x) \, | \, x \in L, \pi_2(x) \in W\}$$ 
where $\pi_1$ is the projection onto $H, \pi_2$ is the projection onto $H^\perp,$ and the window $W \subset H^\perp$ is a ball.

Fix $\epsilon > 0.$ In order to approximate $\Lambda$ to within $\epsilon$ in the Hausdorff distance, we can think of placing $\epsilon$-balls around each point in $\Lambda.$ We want $\Lambda_W$ to have exactly one point in each of these $\epsilon$-balls. Since the full projection of $L$ onto $H$ is dense and uniformly distributed, we can choose $W$ large enough so that $\Lambda_W$ has at least one point in each of these $\epsilon$-balls, however it will also contain other points. Choose one point from each ball and denote this set by $\Lambda_A.$ This shows that $\Lambda$ can be approximated up to $\epsilon$ in the Hausdorff distance by a Meyer set, but $\Lambda_A$ may not be a cut and project set.

Is there some criterion by which we can choose $\Lambda_A$ so that it is necessarily a model set?

EDIT: If this is too difficult, what I would really like to know is whether any Delone set $\Lambda$ can be approximated by a set with has pure discrete spectrum, which would immediately be implied by the result above.

Comment: Could you either define or point to a definition of what constitutes a *model set*? Thanks.

Comment: Edited to include complete definition of $\Lambda_W.$ A cut and project set (or model set) is any set of the same form as $\Lambda_W$ above, where we can vary the lattice $L,$ the subspace $H,$ and the window $W,$ so long as $H$ remains in irrational position w.r.t. $L.$ A Meyer set is any subset of a model set.

Comment: Is Delone an alternate spelling of Boris Delaunay (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boris_Delaunay), or is that someone else?

Comment: I think that's right? I've seen both spellings in papers before.

Comment: The Delaunay triangulation is almost universally spelled that way, as in the original French form of the name, instead of the Cyrillic transliteration...

Comment: The vast majority of recent papers in the theory of tilings use the spelling Delone, although the spelling Delaunay can be found in some older papers. Examples: http://arxiv.org/abs/1411.0578, http://arxiv.org/abs/1401.3725, http://arxiv.org/abs/1407.1787.

Comment: I make no comment on what the spelling ought to be, nor do I have any power over how it is generally used, as this type of choice is made over time, often somewhat arbitrarily, by the community at large...